fail to connect hive from a Kubernetes pod
I am trying to connect a hive server from a Kubernetes pod
following code run well on a windows VM, but failed on a  Kubernetes pod, the base image of the pod is amazoncorretto:17.0.11-alpine
package com.company;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String krb5Path = System.getProperty("krb5Path");
        String keytabPath = System.getProperty("keytabPath");
        String username = System.getProperty("username");
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:hive2://XXXXX000100:10000/default;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationSchema=javaKerberos;principal=hive/XXXXX000100@XXXXX.NET";
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(krb5Path)) {
            krb5Path = "/etc/krb5.conf";
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(keytabPath)) {
            keytabPath = "/etc/XXXXX_test.keytab";
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            username = "XXXXX-test@XXXXX.NET";
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("================start config krb5.conf[%s] and keytab[%s]s==============", krb5Path, keytabPath));
        System.setProperty(
                "java.security.krb5.conf", krb5Path);


        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();

        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

        try {

            UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);


            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(username, keytabPath);
            System.out.println("================login user from keytab success!=================");

            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);

            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("=============Connected to Hive successfully.===============");
                try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                     ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                             "SELECT * FROM default.bp_mapping limit 1")) {
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


krb5.conf
    [libdefaults]
        forwardable = true
        renewable = true
        default_realm = XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.NET
        ticket_lifetime = 24h
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = false
        default_keytab_name = /etc/XXXXX.keytab
        default_ccache_name = /dev/shm/ccache

    [realms]
        XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX.NET = {
            admin_server = XXXXX000111
            kdc = XXXXX000111
        }

jar package run by command:
java --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED  -DkeytabPath=/etc/XXXXX.keytab -jar test-hive-connection.jar
erro we got:
customerservice-d4ff7599d-cwkc9:/etc$ java --add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED  -jar test-hive-connection.jar
================start config krb5.conf[/etc/krb5.conf] and keytab[/etc/XXXXXX_test.keytab]s==============
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See
https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders
for further details.
================login user from keytab success!=================
May 23, 2024 11:19:33 AM org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL
INFO: Supplied authorities: ICSA3M000100:10000
May 23, 2024 11:19:33 AM org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL
INFO: Resolved authority: XXXXX000100:10000
May 23, 2024 11:19:33 AM org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection openTransport
WARNING: Failed to connect to XXXXX000100:10000
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://XXXXX000100:10000/default;principal=hive/XXXXXX000100@XXXXXX.XXXXXX.NET: GSS initiate failed
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:268)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:206)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:42)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:316)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:439)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:244)
... 5 more
It seems login successfully, but Failed to connect to XXXXX000100:10000 with error GSS initiate failed
